# 77-digit number divisible by 7 with seven 7s

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, calculation-puzzle

The smallest number divisible by 7 with seven 7s is trivially 7777777.

Then, what is the greatest 77-digit number divisible by 7 which contains seven 7s?

Comment: Exactly seven 7s, or at least seven 7s?

Comment: quite ironic this puzzle has seven upvotes (at the time of writing) ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor No matter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starting with the factoid that

> 111111 (3 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 37)

is divisible by seven, we can tell that

> 999999 is too, so if we have any number that's divisible by 7, we can put six nines in front of it and still get a number that's divisible by seven.

So, we can focus on

> finding the largest number with 11 digits that's divisible by seven, and has 7 sevens: we can later prepend 66 nines to it.

Being greedy, we should first try the biggest possible such number,

> 99,997,777,777.

To check its divisibility, we can use the divisibility rules for 7:

> we can combine two consecutive sets of 3 digits by subtracting one from the other (this is equivalent to subtracting multiples of 1001, which is divisible by seven), and once we have reached 3 digits, we can subtract twice the last digit from the number formed by the first two.

Both of those operations result in a number that's divisible by seven if and only if they were performed on a number that was divisible by seven. So we get

> 99,997,777,777 -> 99,997,000,000 -> 99,997 -> 997-99 = 898 -> 89-16 = 73.

Sadly, not a multiple of seven. The next biggest is

> 99,987,777,777

No luck there, either. The next two are

> 99,979,777,777 and 99,978,777,777

but alas, no. Moving along in a similar manner, we have to try a couple more until we hit

> 99,977,787,777 (7 times 14282541111)

which gives the final solution of

> **69 nines followed by 77787777**

Answer (score 12):

It is

> $999...99977787777$

> We can find this by hand using le p'tit Fermat:
>  
>  $10^{77} = 10^{13\times 6 - 1} = 10^{-1} = 5 \mod 7$
>  
>  $10^{8} = 2 \mod 7$
>  
>  Taking the difference and replacing $0$s with $7$s:
>  
>  $999...99977777777 = 3 \mod 7$
>  
>  We need to check increments $2\times 10^7,10^7,2\times 10^6,10^6,2\times 10^5,...$ yielding $6,3,2,1,3,5,1,4,... \mod 7$.
>  So the largest usable increment is $10^4$.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to change to a more maimstream notation for "modulo". And while at it I also got rid of "I think", your argument is as good as anyone could ask.

Comment: Thanks @PaulPanzer. That is reassuring.

Answer (score 3):

Brute force solution in Ruby code:

> n = 10**77
>  until (n % 7).zero? && (n.to_s.count('7') == 7) do
>    n -= 1
>  end
>  n
>  #=> 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999977787777

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's:

> Sixty-nine 9s followed by 74777777

Comment: Why not put the 4 at the end? And maybe then add 203?

Comment: Oh, yeah. I wasn't thinking clearly.